# R cannot write a matrix out

Tags: r

I have a matrix that looks like this:

```
ultimate_lof_table[1:5,1:5]
        ACAP3 ACOT7 AGRN AGTRAP ANGPTL7
PT-1S8D     0     0    0      0       0
PT-1S69     0     0    0      0       0
PT-1S19     0     0    0      0       0
PT-1S6E     0     0    0      0       0
PT-1S71     0     0    0      0       0
```

I want to do this:

```
write.table(ultimate_lof_table, file="testchunk1", row.names=T, col.names=T, quote=F)
```

But it cannot write out. The file is blank. What is the problem here?

Comment: Try adding a file extension to your file name

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have defined your wd...the only thing missing seems like an extension on your file.  The only other thing I might add would be to define how you are separating your fields (sep=).

Maybe something like this:

```
write.table(ultimate_lof_table, file="testchunk1.txt", sep="\t", row.names=T, col.names=T, quote=F)
```